# How to declare a vector of structure of a class

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class with a structure in it. How do I create a vector of this structure type?

Here is the example:

```
class A {
public:
    struct mystruct {   
        mystruct (int _label, double _dist) : label(_label), dist(_dist) {}   
        int label;
        double dist;
    };
}
```

Now in this class "A" there is a function as below.

```
   myfunc ( vector<mystruct> &mystry );
```

So my question is I need to call this function with vector of structure. How can I declare this?

Comment: You have to include all namespaces and class scope the `struct` is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the scope operator `::`:

```
std::vector<A::mystruct>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I created a vector and passed it to the function. I am getting the ollowing error "File cannot be opened for writing!"

Comment: @2vision2 That error is completely irrelevant to your use of the vector. You should possibly post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A 
{
public:
    struct mystruct
    {   
        mystruct ( int _label, double _dist ) : label (_label), dist (_dist) {}   
        int label;
        double dist;
    };

    void myfunc(std::vector<mystruct> &mystr);
}
```

As long as you declare myfunc after mystruct you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you *declare* the method of A, `mystruct` is already in scope, so you can use it without qualification:

```
class A {
public:
    struct mystruct {   
        mystruct (int _label, double _dist) : label(_label), dist(_dist) {}   
        int label;
        double dist;
    };

    void myfunc(std::vector<mystruct> &);
}
```

but when you call it, what you *call* the argument type depends on where you are:

```
void free_function() {
    A a;
    std::vector<A::mystruct> arg;
    a.myfunc(arg);
}

void A::another_method() {
    std::vector<mystruct> arg;
    this->myfunc(arg);
}
```

Comment: Using the this pointer inside a class to call a member function is however pretty useless. Just use: myfunc(arg).

Comment: It doesn't _do_ anything, but sometimes it's clearer to read. Here, I wanted to emphasize the symmetry between the free function and the method.